# Can not connect to remote SQL Server using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, remote-server, sqlcmd

I have a Microsoft SQL Server, running in a Window Server 2012 R2 Standard. The configuration for this SQL Instance is: Servername: *IP\SQLEXPRESS*( IP here is the IP address of the Window Server) with SQL authentication username and password.

I would like to connect to this remote database from my local machine, so I installed **sqlcmd** on my local machine Win 7, and tried the syntax to connect to this remote server: `sqlcmd -S IP\SQLEXPRESS -U username -P password`, but then I got some error messages:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SQL Server
>   Network Inte rfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
>   [xFFFFFFFF]. .
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout
>   expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A
>   network-related or in stance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server . Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i f SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see  SQL
>   Server Books Online..

I searched some solutions in the Internet and did some configurations for the SQL Server, such as: enabled remote connection in SQL Server, activate TCP/IP Protocol, open incoming TCP Port 1433 by defining new rule in Windows Firewall of remote server, open outgoing TCP Port 1433 in my local Win 7 machine. But it seems there changes are not work in my case. Can anyone give me some hints here to fix this remote connecting problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you restart SQL Server after enabling remote connections? Make sure the SQL Server Browser service is running to resolve the instance name to dynamic port. Named instances like SQLEXPRESS may listen on a different port. Check low-level port connectivity with this PowerShell command: `powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('yourserver', 1433)) "success"`

Comment: @DanGuzman hi Dan, yes I did restart the SQL Server after enabling remote connections and SQL Server Browser service is also running. Only I tried your PowerShell command check from my local machine but it was not successful. I got the error something like the server is not response, MethodInvocationException and SocketException. Do you have any idea about this exception?

Comment: That means the client cannot reach the port, either because the server isn't listening or the port is blocked. First. check the SQL Server error log to see what interfaces and ports SQL Server is listening on.

Comment: I did check the SQL Server Error log file, and here what I see: The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/VMPW-QA:SQLEXPRESS ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63.

The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/VMPW-QA:1433 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63

Comment: Do you see "listening" messages, like "SQL Server is listening on [ 'any' ipv4 1433]"? The SPN messages are not related to IP connectivity.

Comment: yes, these messages are like: 2018-01-05 14:00:21.85 spid15s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
2018-01-05 14:00:21.85 spid15s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
2018-01-05 14:00:21.85 spid15s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 49216].
2018-01-05 14:00:21.85 spid15s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 49216].

Comment: Knowing SQL is actually listening on 1433, the issue must be related to blocked network traffic. In addition to Windows firewall, do you have other firewalls between the 2 boxes?

Comment: yes you are right, I have a here a Firewall problem. I did open the Firewall from my local computer, but there still have a Firewall between my network. That I had to contact my Network Admin to open it and now it works. Thank you for your time on helping me @DanGuzman :)

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

try use only `sqlcmd -S IP`
not `IP\SQLEXPRESS`